# Conditional spring bean creation

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have a question about Spring annotation configurations. I have a bean:

```
@Bean 
public ObservationWebSocketClient observationWebSocketClient(){
    log.info("creating web socket connection...");
    return new ObservationWebSocketClient();
}
```

and I have a property file:

```
@Autowired
Environment env;
```

In the property file I want to have a special boolean property

```
createWebsocket=true/false
```

which signs whether a bean ObservationWebSocketClient should be created. If property value is false I don't want to establish web socket connection at all.

Is there any technical possibility to realize this?

Comment: Don't have a direct answer to your question, but is maybe a spring profile suitable for you? So the bean gets created only in the profile where it is needed (e.g. test, development, production ...)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Though I've not used this functionality, it appears that you can do this with spring 4's [`@Conditional` annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html).

First, create a `Condition` class, in which the `ConditionContext` has access to the `Environment`:

```
public class MyCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, 
                           AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        Environment env = context.getEnvironment();
        return null != env 
               && "true".equals(env.getProperty("createWebSocket"));
    }
}
```

Then annotate your bean:

```
@Bean
@Conditional(MyCondition.class)
public ObservationWebSocketClient observationWebSocketClient(){
    log.info("creating web socket connection...");
    return new ObservationWebSocketClient();
}
```

**edit** The `spring-boot` annotation `@ConditionalOnProperty` has implemented this generically; the source code for the `Condition` used to evaluate it [is available on github here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/OnPropertyCondition.java) for those interested. If you find yourself often needing this funcitonality, using a similar implementation would be advisable rather than making lots of custom `Condition` implementations.

Comment: @chrylis What's the better solution? Returning `null` from the `observationWebSocketClient` method?

Comment: Posted (took a while to type on mobile).

Comment: Please have a look at below suggestion of using ConditionalOnProperty. That seems to be more effective.

Comment: And what if the createWebsocket=true/false flag is came from database?

Answer (score 50):

Annotate your bean method with `@ConditionalOnProperty("createWebSocket")`.

Note that Spring Boot offers a number of useful conditions prepackaged.

Comment: Is this `spring-boot` specific?

Comment: @beerbajay I don't believe so, and if it is, the annotation can be included without enabling autoconfiguration. It's essentially very similar to your suggestion, except generalized and pre-implemented.

Comment: Hrmm, appears to be `spring-boot` only: [javadocs](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html)

Comment: So include the artifact with the annotation and don't use autoconfiguration. The nifty thing about Boot is that it's just a set of rules on top of the core condition system and can be used in bits and pieces.

Answer (score 3):

For Spring Boot 2+ you can simply use:

```
@Profile("prod")
or
@Profile({"prod","stg"})
```

That will allow you to filter the desired profile/profiles, for production or staging and for the underlying Bean using that annotation it only will be loaded by Springboot when you set the variable spring.profiles.active is equals to "prod" and ("prod" or "stg"). That variable can be set on O.S. environment variables or using command line, such as -Dspring.profiles.active=prod.

Answer (score 1):

As for me, this problem can be solved by using Spring 3.1 `@Profiles`, because `@Conditional` annotation give you opportunity for define some strategy for conditional bean registration (user-defined strategies for conditional checking), when `@Profiles` can based logic only on `Environment` variables only.