# Conditionally create a Bean given a situation where the String is null

Tags: java, spring

How can I conditionally create a Bean given a situation where the String is null?

The following example would cause an error, but I would like to somehow prevent it from happening by only creating beans when the string being assessed is not empty.

```
public class MyAppContext

  @Value("${this.string.is.null}")
  private String nullString;

  @SupressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
  @Bean
  public MessageListenerContainer myQueue() {
    bean.setDestinationName(nullString)
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844271/conditional-spring-bean-creation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `@ConditionalOnExpression` annotation:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${this.string.is.null}'!=null")
public MessageListener myQueue() {
    bean.setDestinationName(nullString)
}
```

Or create a custom condition:

```
public class MyPropNotNull implements Condition {

    public MyPropNotNull() {}

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        Environment env = context.getEnvironment();
        return env.getProperty("this.string.is.null") != null;
    }
}

@Bean
@Conditional(MyPropNotNull.class)
public MessageListener myQueue() {
    bean.setDestinationName(nullString)
}
```

**Update**: if having a bean of this type is mandatory, don't forget to add a fallback bean. Example:

```
 @ConditionalOnMissingBean
 @Bean
 public MessageListener useThisOneWhenTheOtherIsMissing() {
     // this bean will be used when the other one is not available
     // ...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Sadly causing autowiring issues right now (failed to instantiate MyPopNotNull... no default constructor found... please help

Comment: @methuselah no default constructor found? that's strange. Can you try adding a default constructor? Updated answer

Comment: Still not working. Getting Failed to load Application context errors

Comment: @methuselah what errors are you getting? it is likely that you get an error if you are trying to use the conditional bean when the condition is false. If a `MessageListener` bean is mandatory, you should have a fallback one for when the condition is not met.

Comment: @methuselah you can use the `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotation for example. I have updated the answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

try https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "propertyName")
@Bean
  public MessageListener myQueue() {
    bean.setDestinationName(nullString)
  }
```