# How to declare an optional @Bean in Spring?

Tags: spring, javabeans

I want to provide an optional `@Bean` in my `@Configuration` file like:

```
@Bean
public Type method(Type dependency) {
    // TODO
}
```

when dependency can't be found, the method should not be called.

How to do that?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844271/conditional-spring-bean-creation You can use `@Conditional`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use [ConditionalOnClass](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnClass.html) If using `SpringBoot` and [Conditional](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) in Spring `since 4.0` [See If using Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844271/conditional-spring-bean-creation)

Example of `SpringBoot` :-

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnClass(value=com.mypack.Type.class)
public Type method() {
    ......
    return ...
}
```

Now the `method()` will be called only  when `com.mypack.Type.class` is in `classpath`.

Answer (score 19):

In addition to the accepted answer, you have to check if the dependency is initialized before calling any method which requires that dependency.

```
@Autowired(required = false) 
Type dependency;

public Type methodWhichRequiresTheBean() {
   ...
}

public Type someOtherMethod() { 
     if(dependency != null) { //Check if dependency initialized
         methodWhichRequiresTheBean();
     }
}
```

Comment: It's not about providing a Bean