# How do I tell Spring to skip loading a Configuration class based on a property?

Tags: java, spring

I know that with the `@Profile` annotation, you can tell Spring to only load a certain class when using the specified profile, like this:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class MyCustomConfigurationClass {
    // this will only be instantiated when the "dev" profile is active
}
```

However I'm wondering if there's some equivalent way of doing that for a given application property / environment variable? Here's some pseudo code to illustrate what I want to do:

```
@Configuration
@OnlyInstantiateWhen(property = "${my.property}", value = "true")
public class MyCustomConfigurationClass {
    // this would theoretically only be instantiated when
    // the value of my.property is true, either in application.properties
    // or in an environment variable
}
```

Is anything like this possible?

Comment: have a look at `@ConditionalOnProperty`: https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html

Comment: That's perfect! `ConditionalOnProperty` is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at implementation of your own condition or using `@ConditionalOnProperty()` like answers for [this question] suggest. ([Conditional spring bean creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844271/conditional-spring-bean-creation/))