# How to control Spring context initialization errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, plugin-architecture

Let say we have a Spring bean:

```
@Component
class PluginsProviderImpl implements PluginsProvider {
    private final List<PluginInterface> plugins;
    public PluginsProviderImpl(List<PluginInterface> plugins){
        this.plugins = plugins;
    }
  //...
}
```

The implementations of `PluginInterface` have runtime dependency with the core system and are provided externally. It is possible that sometimes, some of them are erroneous (e.g. their dependencies are missing). If there is a such an error while Spring context initialization - the whole application does not start (even thou the broken plugin is not required to its proper operation).

Is it possible to control Spring context loading in such a way that, if error occurs in one of the `PluginInterface` implementations, skip it and proceed with initialization?

UPDATE: More explanation: I Do not need to add a bean conditionally. I want to skip a bean that is erroneous and the problem appears  during context initialization. This is a plugin - provided at runtime.

Even more explanation:
I want to application start even if one of the plugin introduced implementations of PluginInterface cannot be initialized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional spring bean creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844271/conditional-spring-bean-creation)

Comment: @RolandWeisleder I Do not need to add a bean conditionally. I want to skip a bean that is erroneous and it is known during context initialization. This is plugin - provided at runtime.

Comment: 'their dependencies are missing' is this the only problem? if not can you explain more what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @slimane In general, I want to application start even if one of the plugin introduced implementations of PluginInterface cannot be initialized.

Comment: @piradian how are those PluginInterface passed to the application?are they spring managed Beans?

Comment: @slimane Yes. But they are provided by "plugin jars"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. It is not perfect but it works in most of cases.
At first I realized that in my case erroneous plugin means the plugin that have **linkage** problem, e.g. someone provide the plugin without runtime dependencies or there is a problem with plugin version against the application version.
Secondly I found a hook in Spring context initialization (bean factory to be precise) that allows to inject code when: `All bean definitions will have been loaded, but no beans will have been instantiated yet. This allows for overriding or adding properties even to eager-initializing beans.`- regardless of Spring documentation info, it also allows for **removing** bean definitions from bean factory. In general it may not be safe operation (in the end, the removed bean my be needed by other bean) but I use it only for plugins instances definition, that are by default independent and self contained. Ok, enough talking about the code, let us see the code... ;)

```
public class PluginQualifierProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PluginQualifierProcessor.class);

@Override
public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
    String[] beanNamesForType = beanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(PluginInterface.class);
    List<String> beans = Arrays.asList(beanNamesForType)
                               .stream()
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (String beanName : beans) {
        BeanDefinition bean = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanName);
        if (!bean.hasConstructorArgumentValues()) {
            String className = bean.getBeanClassName();
            try {
                tryToInstatiate(className);
                // we are interested only in runtime linkage errors that can happen if plugin is erroneous
            } catch (LinkageError e) {
                LOGGER.error("plugin {} is erroneous. It will be discarded from context. {}", className, e);
                ((BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory).removeBeanDefinition(beanName);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void tryToInstatiate(String className) {
    try {
        Class<?> beanClass = Class.forName(className);
        beanClass.newInstance();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        LOGGER.debug("skip exception while creating instance of {}. {}", className, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

The key fragment is:

```
catch (LinkageError e) {
                ((BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory).removeBeanDefinition(beanName);
  }
```

We catch LinkageError (not an Exception!) because we search for broken implemenations and as Java documentation says

> Subclasses of LinkageError indicate that a class has some dependency on another class; however, the latter class has incompatibly changed after the compilation of the former class

.

As I found out, it also indicates the lack of the dependency.
A the begining I wrote that this solution is not perfect. The code checks if the plugin has parameteless constructor to instantiatiate it. If plugin do not have one - cannot be checked. So I need to ad additional requirement for plugins - they must have parameterless constructor :).