# spring-boot create bean only when action is called

Tags: spring-boot, spring-bean, mongotemplate

I have some some spring configuration code which creates the spring bean

```
@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
}
```

In some class I am using like below

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate  mongoTemplate ;
```

Bean in getting created whenever spring is started but due to some some service I want to make sure bean should be created only when action is invoked on the object

like mongoTemplate.save etc

Comment: This might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844271/conditional-spring-bean-creation

Comment: Did you think about using spring lazy loading ? or It doesn't fit your need ?

Comment: Creating a MonoTemplate on each call is probably (im saying probably) not good performance wise....

Answer (score 1):

[Proxy by CGLIB](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ScopedProxyMode.html) and [lazy-initialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html) are available.

```java
    @Lazy
    @Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    }
```

- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factorybeans-annotations